# What should I look to do in high school to prepare myself for college/jobs

Tags: education

I am a high schooler who has been programming for about 3 years now. My skill level is above what AP Comp Sci and especially what principles can teach me. What should I be doing to improve myself and prepare for future schools/jobs? What should I be adding to my portfolio?

Comment: This [answer](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/4912/1940) of mine on CS Educators Stackexchange may be of interest.

Comment: Competitive Programming. Top coder, hackerrank, advent of code, project Euler, ...

Comment: Thanks for the resources @PålGD . Besides just practice problems and puzzles is there anything else I should be looking to add my portfolio? I’ve heard that contributing to open source projects can help a lot but I’m not sure if I’m ready. I’d love some more insight

Comment: @Pixeled You don't have to contribute to existing open source projects. You can create your own projects, anything you are passionate or particularly curious about and would like to explore. In high-school I started out with simply OS utilities, a mathematical function graphing utility, a Morse code generator, a simple math library, and wrote documentation for most of those projects. As a university student I expanded into more ambitious projects, some of which I published about in hobbyist magazines and later (> 1990) on the internet. One in the latter group got me my first Silicon Valley job

Comment: @njuffa I've been wanting to start some sort of big project but I just can't come up with any ideas. I'm into CLI apps and working with OOP and structs but I feel like it's so hard to find original things to do. Do you have any tips for thinking of ideas?

Comment: @Pixeled Rather than focusing on identifying some big project, why not start with something small that strikes you as interesting *now*, and let things progress organically from there? My experience is that an answered question often leads to a new set of questions. With one topic, I started with something simple in high school, expanded on it during my university years, then worked on it professionally (in both hardware and software contexts) on multiple occasions, and am still exploring aspects of it in retirement. It's not about being original but the independent pursuit of a topic.

Comment: @njuffa thanks for the advice!